# Undefined method `stringify_keys' when calling update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error: undefined method `stringify_keys' for :environ_gross_score:Symbol
when I attempt to create a new rating.

```
  class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city


  after_save :calculate_rating


 def calculate_rating
     @env  =   self.environ

     self.city.environ_vote_count += 1                                  
     @c = self.city.environ_gross_score
     @gross = @c += @env
     self.city.update_attributes(:environ_gross_score, @gross )
     @hold = self.city.environ_gross_score / self.city.environ_vote_count 
     self.city.update_attributes(:environ_rating, @hold)
end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`update_attributes` takes a single hash, not 2 parameters.  Change the line to:

```
 self.city.update_attributes(:environ_gross_score => @gross)
```

The error was happening because the method assumed that the first argument passed was a hash, which does (in Rails) respond to `stringify_keys`.